# Why does importing a file that contains a print() cause the output to be printed?

Tags: python, import

Consider the following Python files

file_one.py:

```
text = ("Sample text")
print(text)
```

file_two.py:

```
import file_one
```

Running `python file_two.py` gives the following output:

```
Sample Text
```

I was wondering why `file_two` automatically prints the output of `file_one` when it has been imported. I thought you may need to specifically call it to print out the text like `print(file_one.text)`.

Similarly, in theory, is this any different from importing libraries such as `random` or `pandas` etc? As in, if they have a line that says `print("hello")`, hello will be printed automatically in the output of the module that imports it?

Answer (score 1):

It’s because files are run when imported.

This might help
https://www.pythonmorsels.com/importing-module-runs-code/

Comment: Thank you so much. This was truly helpful. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a file, everything at the top level of the file (that isn't part of a class or function) is run immediately.

That includes imports of other modules.